# Debug in Eclipse (Lua and LDT); can't hover over a variable to view the value

Tags: eclipse, lua

When I am debugging a local Lua source file in the debug perspective, and stopped at a breakpoint, Eclipse does not display variable values upon hovering over them with a mouse.

I have looked in Window->Lua->Editor, but I do not see a setting that can be changed to achieve the desired behaviour.

I can see the variable's value under Global variables in the Variables tab, but this is highly inconvenient. (I can also add the variable to the Expressions view, but this is not very convenient either).

Is this a bug? A setting that is not selected by default?

I am running Eclipse 4.4.1 and I have installed the Lua Development Tools add on (1.3.0.201502261548).

For instance, if I put a breakpoint on the line 'print(x)', hovering over the variable x does not show its value:

```
local function main()
x = 2.44
print(x)
end
main()
```

[image: Hovering in debug does not show value of variable]

Comment: As an alternative, you could add x to Expressions.

Comment: No, even if I use an expression, hovering over the variable does not show its value in the debugger.

Comment: I just meant that the Expressions tab is a lot less inconvenient than the globals section of the Variables tab.

Comment: Ah, I see. That is better than scrolling through the global variables, but still not nearly as convenient as hovering over the variable. Thank you